# Keras: is there sample code for train_on_batch which has history + progress?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In Python, I'm moving from Keras's `Model.fit` to a `Model.train_on_batch` loop for finer control. But the progress bar and History object returned by `fit` are useful. Before wasting time implementing them from scratch, I was wondering if anyone had found sample code using `train_on_batch` that reproduced the progress bar and history?

(NB. I had a look at the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/70038da9c5f7de1a4bd3ab15551d37a02a6c3ae9/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L854) for `fit`, but there's enough layers of indirection that it's not easy to dig out exactly what it's doing. Also found [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/keras-custom-training-loop-59ce779d60fb), which is helpful but doesn't have the relevant functionality.)

Comment: Isn't the a `verbose` parameter that can be set to 1?

Comment: @CeliusStingher There is one in `fit`, which causes the progress bar to be shown. There's nothing of the kind in `train_on_batch`.

Comment: Hmm. Looks like the progress/history functionality is set up in https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/CallbackList.

Comment: You could just using `tf.print('.', end='')` after each `Model.train_on_batch` to show the progress, and at end of each epoch, print the info you need (e.g loss or gradients)

Comment: @Mr.ForExample I could, but it would completely flood the screen. The built in progress bar works nicely in a Jupyter notebook. And the history object has a lot of useful methods.

Don't get me wrong, it's feasible to reimplement everything. But it's reinventing the wheel...

Comment: @Mohan, wait minute, I just look at source code for a minutes, isn't the [tf.keras.callbacks.ProgbarLogger](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ProgbarLogger) is the things you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having defined `EPOCHS`, `train_generator` and validation data `val_x, val_y`, you can replace

```
history = model.fit(train_generator, validation_data = (val_x, val_y), epochs = EPOCHS)
```

with the following code:

```
callbacks = tf.keras.callbacks.CallbackList(
    None, 
    add_history = True,
    add_progbar = True,
    model = model,
    epochs = EPOCHS,
    verbose = 1,
    steps = len(train_generator)
)

callbacks.on_train_begin()
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    model.reset_metrics()
    callbacks.on_epoch_begin(epoch)
    for i in range(len(train_generator)):
        callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(i)
        logs = model.train_on_batch(*train_generator[i], reset_metrics = False, return_dict = True)              
        callbacks.on_train_batch_end(i, logs)

    validation_logs = model.evaluate(val_x, val_y, callbacks = callbacks, return_dict = True)
    logs.update({'val_' + name: v for name, v in validation_logs.items()})

    callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
    train_generator.on_epoch_end()

callbacks.on_train_end(epoch_logs)
history = model.history
```

Comment: Yes, one could also using `tf.keras.callbacks.CallbackList` directly, I should've mentioned that before I go to bed last night, anyway, from now on this shouldn't be problem to anyone anymore : ) cheers

Comment: This is amazing, however, where does the "epoch_logs" variable come from?

Answer (score 2):

So after looking at source code of keras, I find the [tf.keras.callbacks.ProgbarLogger](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ProgbarLogger) and [tf.keras.callbacks.History](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/History) is what you want

Source code

[keras/callbacks.py#L259](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.1/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py#L259)

[keras/callbacks.py#L263](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.1/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py#L263)

Comment: It's messy. I get the impression those classes aren't really designed to be used directly. (I'm using the CallbackList functionality I mentioned to create those two objects rather than doing it directly, but I don't think that is the cause.) 

Thanks for the help, though. I wouldn't worry about this any more. I'll keep tweaking until it works + post a full code sample. I just wanted to check that someone hadn't already done that somewhere...

Comment: To expand on that 'messy' comment, there's various undocumented gubbins. E.g. epochs are 0-indexed in the code but 1-indexed in the printed output, and the output is very confusing if you pass in 1-indexed epochs.