# Change Verbosity of Keras train_on_batch()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence

I am training a GAN using Keras's `train_on_batch()` command. This is very similar to Keras's `fit()`. However, in the documentation for `fit()`, there is a parameter for `verbose`, which changes how often a progress bar is printed to the console.

My model has many batches, and so it is printing tons of progress bars to the command line. Unfortunately, `train_on_batch()` does not have a `verbose` parameter. Is there a workaround for this? Is there a Keras global variable/environment variable that I can set? I don't want to disable my program from printing to the console, I just want to change the verbosity of specifically `train_on_batch()`.

For clarify, I am using Keras directly from the Keras package, I am not using tf.keras.

Comment: Pointer: https://keras.io/api/callbacks/progbar_logger/

Comment: @Innat even though I am not using tf.keras, will this still work?

Comment: What do you neamn not tf.keras but keras? If you're using old keras, you can check if this callback is available or not.

Comment: @Innat I was using old Keras. I just switched to tf.keras. However, `callbacks` is not an argument for model.train_on_batch() so I can't use this, I don't think

Comment: Can you add minimum code with `train_on_batch` (with dummy data)?

Comment: Or, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65260248/9215780, might be helpful.